# .netcore sockets break while classic .net still works

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core

I have client and server written in classic .net communicating through TCP sockets. I also have load tests with many parallel connections and it all works.

However, same code using .netcore breaks. On linux it breaks all the time with client getting exceptions while trying to read from stream:

> Client socket error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection timed out.

Or server might return 0 as bytes to read as well.

On Windows .netcore client breaks less often, but still breaks sometimes with error like:

> socket error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond

.netcore 3.0 by the way.

Any ideas why that happens?

Client:

```
    public class TcpConnection
    {
        object _lock = new object();
        bool _is_busy = false;
        public bool TakeLock()
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_is_busy)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    _is_busy = true;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        public void ReleaseLock()
        {
            _is_busy = false;
        }
        public bool Connected { get; set; }
        public string ConnError { get; set; }
        public Socket client { get; set; }
        public Stream stream { get; set; }
        public BinaryWriter bw { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUsed { get; set; }
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public TcpConnection(string hostname, int port)
        {
            client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            SocketAsyncEventArgs connectEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            connectEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(ConnectedEvent);
            connectEventArg.UserToken = this;
            connectEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(hostname), port);
            var connected = client.ConnectAsync(connectEventArg);
            if (!connected)
            {
                if (connectEventArg.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
                {
                    #if (VERBOSE)
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection error (immediate)");
                    #endif
                    throw new LinqDbException("Linqdb: Connection error (immediate)");
                }
                #if (VERBOSE)
                Console.WriteLine("Connected immediately");
                #endif
                //client.NoDelay = true;
                client.ReceiveTimeout = 60000;
                client.SendTimeout = 60000;
                this.stream = new NetworkStream(client);
                this.bw = new BinaryWriter(stream);
            }
            else
            {
                int total_wait_ms = 0;
                while (!this.Connected)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);

                    total_wait_ms += 100;
                    #if (VERBOSE)
                    if (total_wait_ms % 2000 == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Can't connect in {0} ms", total_wait_ms);
                    }
                    #endif
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ConnError))
                {
                    throw new LinqDbException(this.ConnError + "  after " + total_wait_ms + " ms wait time");
                }
                else
                {
                    #if (VERBOSE)
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected {0} ms", total_wait_ms);
                    #endif
                }
            }
            _is_busy = true;
            LastUsed = DateTime.Now;
        }
        private void ConnectedEvent(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            TcpConnection conn = e.UserToken as TcpConnection;
            if (e.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
            {
                #if (VERBOSE)
                Console.WriteLine("Connection error");
                #endif
                conn.ConnError = "Connection error";
                conn.Connected = true;
                return;
            }
            //e.ConnectSocket.NoDelay = true;
            e.ConnectSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 60000;
            e.ConnectSocket.SendTimeout = 60000;

            conn.stream = new NetworkStream(conn.client);
            conn.bw = new BinaryWriter(conn.stream);
            conn.ConnError = null;
            conn.Connected = true;
        }        
    }

    public class ClientSockets
    {

        const int _limit = 100;
        TcpConnection[] cons = new TcpConnection[_limit];
        object _lock = new object();
        object[] _locks = null;

        public byte[] CallServer(byte[] input, string hostname, int port, out string error_msg)
        {
            error_msg = null;
            if (_locks == null)
            {
                lock (_lock)
                {
                    if (_locks == null)
                    {
                        _locks = new object[_limit];
                        for (int i = 0; i < _limit; i++)
                        {
                            _locks[i] = new object();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            TcpConnection conn = null;
            while (true)
            {
                int last_index = 0;
                for (int i = _limit - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (cons[i] != null)
                    {
                        last_index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < _limit; i++)
                {
                    var tmp = cons[i];
                    if (tmp != null)
                    {
                        var available = tmp.TakeLock();
                        if (!available)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if ((DateTime.Now - tmp.LastUsed).TotalSeconds > 30)
                            {
                                cons[i] = null;
                                try
                                {
                                    tmp.client.Dispose();
                                    tmp.stream.Dispose();
                                    tmp.bw.Dispose();
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
#if (VERBOSE)
                                    Console.WriteLine("Disposing error:" + ex.Message);
#endif
                                }
                                continue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //ping
                                tmp.bw.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(-3));
                                tmp.bw.Flush();

                                int numBytesRead = 0;
                                var data = new byte[1024];
                                var bad = false;
                                while (numBytesRead < 4)
                                {
                                    int read = 0;
                                    try
                                    {
                                        read = tmp.stream.Read(data, numBytesRead, data.Length - numBytesRead);
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        //server closed connection
                                        bad = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    numBytesRead += read;
                                    if (read <= 0)
                                    {
                                        //server closed connection
                                        bad = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (bad)
                                {
                                    cons[i] = null;
                                    try
                                    {
                                        tmp.client.Dispose();
                                        tmp.stream.Dispose();
                                        tmp.bw.Dispose();
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
#if (VERBOSE)
                                    Console.WriteLine("Disposing error:" + ex.Message);
#endif
                                    }
                                    continue;
                                }
                                var pong = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[4] { data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3] }, 0);
                                if (pong != -3)
                                {
                                    cons[i] = null;
                                    try
                                    {
                                        tmp.client.Dispose();
                                        tmp.stream.Dispose();
                                        tmp.bw.Dispose();
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
#if (VERBOSE)
                                    Console.WriteLine("Disposing error:" + ex.Message);
#endif
                                    }
                                    continue;
                                }

                                //socket is ok
                                conn = tmp;
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i < last_index)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (Monitor.TryEnter(_locks[i]))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                if (cons[i] != null)
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                conn = new TcpConnection(hostname, port);
                                cons[i] = conn;
                                conn.Index = i;
                                break;
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                conn = null;
                                cons[i] = null;
                                #if (VERBOSE)
                                Console.WriteLine("Client socket creation error: " + ex.Message);
                                #endif
                                error_msg = ex.Message;
                                return BitConverter.GetBytes(-1);
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                Monitor.Exit(_locks[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (conn == null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(150);
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            bool error = false;
            try
            {
                var length = BitConverter.GetBytes(input.Length);
                var data = new byte[1024];
                conn.bw.Write(input);
                conn.bw.Flush();

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int numBytesRead;
                    int total;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        numBytesRead = 0;
                        while (numBytesRead < 4)
                        {
                            int read = conn.stream.Read(data, numBytesRead, data.Length - numBytesRead);
                            numBytesRead += read;
                            if (read <= 0)
                            {
                                throw new LinqDbException("Read <= 0: " + read);
                            }
                        }
                        numBytesRead -= 4;
                        total = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[4] { data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3] }, 0);
                        if (total == -2)
                        {
                            #if (VERBOSE)
                            Console.WriteLine("PINGER!!!");
                            #endif
                            continue;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    if (numBytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        var finput = new byte[numBytesRead];
                        for (int i = 0; i < numBytesRead; i++)
                        {
                            finput[i] = data[4 + i];
                        }
                        ms.Write(finput, 0, numBytesRead);
                    }
                    total -= numBytesRead;
                    while (total > 0)
                    {
                        numBytesRead = conn.stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        if (numBytesRead <= 0)
                        {
                            throw new LinqDbException("numBytesRead <= 0: " + numBytesRead);
                        }
                        ms.Write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
                        total -= numBytesRead;
                    }
                    conn.LastUsed = DateTime.Now;
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                #if (VERBOSE)
                Console.WriteLine("Client socket error: " + ex.Message);
                #endif
                error = true;
                error_msg = ex.Message;
                return BitConverter.GetBytes(-1);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!error)
                {
                    conn.ReleaseLock();
                }
                else
                {
                    cons[conn.Index] = null;
                    try
                    {
                        conn.client.Dispose();
                        conn.stream.Dispose();
                        conn.bw.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        #if (VERBOSE)
                        Console.WriteLine("Disposing error:" + ex.Message);
                        #endif
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Server:

```
    class Pinger
    {
        public bool Done { get; set; }
        public object _lock = new object();
        public BinaryWriter bw { get; set; }
        public void Do()
        {
            try
            {
                int total_wait = 0;
                int sleep_ms = 2000;
                while (!Done)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(sleep_ms);
                    total_wait += sleep_ms;
                    if (total_wait % 10000 == 0)
                    {
                        lock (_lock)
                        {
                            if (!Done)
                            {
                                bw.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(-2));
                                bw.Flush();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { return; }
        }
    }
    class ServerSockets
    {
        static Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        static string db_path = null;
        static int port = 0;
        public static void Main()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);
            CommandHelper.ReadConfig(out db_path, out port);
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Building in-memory indexes...");
            ServerLogic.Logic.ServerBuildIndexesOnStart(db_path);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Done building in-memory indexes. It took: " + Math.Round(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 60000.0, 0) + " min.");

            Console.WriteLine("Listening on " + port);
            listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
            listener.Listen((int)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections);


            SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            acceptEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(Service);
            bool willRaiseEvent = listener.AcceptAsync(acceptEventArg);
            if (!willRaiseEvent)
            {
                Service(null, acceptEventArg);
            }

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(60000);
                    #if (VERBOSE)
                    Console.WriteLine("Still kicking...");
                    #endif
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("BAD ERROR... " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServerLogic.Logic.Dispose();
        }
        private static void LoopToStartAccept()
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            acceptEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(Service);
            bool willRaiseEvent = listener.AcceptAsync(acceptEventArg);
            if (!willRaiseEvent)
            {
                Service(null, acceptEventArg);
            }
        }
        private static void HandleBadAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptEventArgs)
        {
            #if (VERBOSE)
            Console.WriteLine("bad accept");
            #endif
            acceptEventArgs.AcceptSocket.Dispose();
        }
        private static void Service(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
            {
                LoopToStartAccept();
                HandleBadAccept(e);
                return;
            }

            LoopToStartAccept();


            try
            {
                using (Socket soc = e.AcceptSocket)
                {
                    var rg = new Random();
                    #if (VERBOSE)
                    Console.WriteLine("New socket: " + rg.Next(0, 1000000));
                    #endif
                    //soc.NoDelay = true;
                    soc.ReceiveTimeout = 60000;
                    soc.SendTimeout = 60000;
                    using (Stream stream = new NetworkStream(soc))
                    using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(stream))
                    {
                        while (true) //reuse same connection for many commands
                        {
                            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                int numBytesRead = 0;
                                while (numBytesRead < 4)
                                {
                                    int read = 0;
                                    try
                                    {
                                        read = stream.Read(data, numBytesRead, data.Length - numBytesRead);
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        //client closed connection
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    numBytesRead += read;
                                    if (read <= 0)
                                    {
                                        //throw new Exception("Read <= 0: " + read);
                                        //client closed connection
                                        return;
                                    }
                                }
                                numBytesRead -= 4;
                                var total = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[4] { data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3] }, 0);
                                if (total == -3) //ping
                                {
                                    //pong
                                    bw.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(-3));
                                    bw.Flush();
                                    continue;
                                }
                                if (numBytesRead > 0)
                                {
                                    var finput = new byte[numBytesRead];
                                    for (int i = 0; i < numBytesRead; i++)
                                    {
                                        finput[i] = data[4 + i];
                                    }
                                    ms.Write(finput, 0, numBytesRead);
                                }
                                total -= numBytesRead;
                                while (total > 0)
                                {
                                    numBytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                                    if (numBytesRead <= 0)
                                    {
                                        throw new Exception("numBytesRead <= 0: " + numBytesRead);
                                    }
                                    ms.Write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
                                    total -= numBytesRead;
                                }
                                var input = ms.ToArray();
                                var pinger = new Pinger()
                                {
                                    bw = bw
                                };
                                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(f => { pinger.Do(); });
                                var output = ServerLogic.Logic.Execute(input, db_path);
                                pinger.Done = true;
                                lock (pinger._lock)
                                {
                                    bw.Write(output);
                                    bw.Flush();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
#if (VERBOSE)
                Console.WriteLine("Socket error: " + ex.Message);
#endif
                //try
                //{
                //    var rg = new Random();
                //    File.WriteAllText("sock_error_" + rg.Next() + ".txt", ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace + (ex.InnerException != null ? (" " + ex.InnerException.Message + " " + ex.InnerException.StackTrace) : ""));
                //}
                //catch (Exception) { }
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                #if (VERBOSE)
                Console.WriteLine("Listener finally ");
                #endif
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
Fully reproducible project: https://github.com/ren85/serverclientbug

**EDIT**
No solution still, 500 more points to whoever can fix this.

**EDIT**
Maybe related
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/11979
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/364

Comment: Two things: One, there are types I can't resolve in your classes. ServerLogic for example. Paste your code into two new .net core projects (one for server/one for client) and you'll see what I mean. Second, there's a definite code-smell around your locking...which I'm nearly certain is the source of your problems: locking on instance variables is the first thing that looks fishy. Consider making your lock objects static and see if that doesn't magically fix things. Also, having a method other than dispose that disposes things you're holding onto...hmmm. Just sayin'.

Comment: What is `LinqDbException`? What is `CommandHelper`? What is `ServerLogic`? Why would you write this `catch { return; }`!

Comment: There are plenty of places where you catch exceptions, write them to the console if `VERBOSE` is defined then otherwise ignore them!

Comment: It seems entirely likely that an informative exception is being thrown and it is simply being ignored on the assumption that an exception at this point must mean *x*. For instance, any exception on this line `read = stream.Read(data, numBytesRead, data.Length - numBytesRead);` is assumed to mean the connection was closed.

Comment: @Jodrell LinqDbException, CommandHelper, ServerLogic are irrelevent, server logic just does some IO work...  . Though many valid points - will have a look.

Comment: @Clay I can't make locks static as that would change logic -  I'm locking per instance (for example Pinger lock). Though it indeed seems like a probable cause of problems (the pingers lock)

Comment: The interesting part is why it works for classic .net and not the netcore

Comment: Haven't examined the source, but would expect that there are plenty of changes from .net core and .net framework. There's a whole new big set of eyes on the core stuff as it comes into being. It's not a drag-n-drop port...and is especially different when one crosses into other-than-originally-written-in worlds. In some cases like this, not getting the exception in threading code involves a certain amount of luck and fortuitous timing. I'd log everything :-)

Comment: @ren, I know that you think some code is not relevant to problem and you are almost certainly right but, without a working example that recreates the issue we can only offer suggestions. This problem is not simple enough to solve without debugging. I might think I've fixed it but, would I be sure?

Comment: @Jodrell https://github.com/ren85/serverclientbug

Comment: Sorry, indeed not included code was important as the answer by AlesD shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily the problem reproduced with just 2 parallel threads. The problem was in server part:

```
private static void LoopToStartAccept()
{
    SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    acceptEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(Service);
    bool willRaiseEvent = listener.AcceptAsync(acceptEventArg);
    if (!willRaiseEvent)
    {
        Service(null, acceptEventArg);
    }
}
```

Service(null, acceptEventArg); blocked responding socket. Changing it to

Task.Run(() => Service(null, acceptEventArg));

fixed the problem. No idea why it worked on Windows though.

Changing connection in client to synchronous as @AlesD suggested also solved some other problems.

Answer (score 10):

I debugged your code and looks like the problem are bugs not issues with sockets in .NET core. From the code it looks you expect that the first four bytes of the data sent will contain the length of the data but you send only the data. This causes that you get a random data length since the first four bytes of the data are used as the length. This in some cases is bigger than the actual data and then the while loop that is reading the data timeouts on waiting for more data that never arrives.

Here is the problematic part of the code in the client:

```
var length = BitConverter.GetBytes(input.Length); // You prepare the length
var data = new byte[1024];
conn.bw.Write(length); // This is missing in your code so it never gets sent to the server
conn.bw.Write(input);
conn.bw.Flush();
```

Full client with the fix included:

```
public class ClientSockets
{

   const int _limit = 100;
   TcpConnection[] cons = new TcpConnection[_limit];
   object _lock = new object();
   object[] _locks = null;

   public byte[] CallServer(byte[] input, string hostname, int port, out string error_msg)
   {
      error_msg = null;
      if (_locks == null)
      {
         lock (_lock)
         {
            if (_locks == null)
            {
               _locks = new object[_limit];
               for (int i = 0; i < _limit; i++)
               {
                  _locks[i] = new object();
               }
            }
         }
      }
      TcpConnection conn = null;
      while (true)
      {
         int last_index = 0;
         for (int i = _limit - 1; i >= 0; i--)
         {
            if (cons[i] != null)
            {
               last_index = i;
               break;
            }
         }
         for (int i = 0; i < _limit; i++)
         {
            var tmp = cons[i];
            if (tmp != null)
            {
               var available = tmp.TakeLock();
               if (!available)
               {
                  continue;
               }
               else
               {
                  if ((DateTime.Now - tmp.LastUsed).TotalSeconds > 30)
                  {
                     cons[i] = null;
                     try
                     {
                        tmp.client.Dispose();
                        tmp.stream.Dispose();
                        tmp.bw.Dispose();
                     }
                     catch (Exception ex)
                     {
#if (VERBOSE)
                                    Console.WriteLine("Disposing error:" + ex.Message);
#endif
                     }
                     continue;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     //ping
                     tmp.bw.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(-3));
                     tmp.bw.Flush();

                     int numBytesRead = 0;
                     var data = new byte[1024];
                     var bad = false;
                     while (numBytesRead < 4)
                     {
                        int read = 0;
                        try
                        {
                           read = tmp.stream.Read(data, numBytesRead, data.Length - numBytesRead);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                           //server closed connection
                           bad = true;
                           break;
                        }
                        numBytesRead += read;
                        if (read <= 0)
                        {
                           //server closed connection
                           bad = true;
                           break;
                        }
                     }
                     if (bad)
                     {
                        cons[i] = null;
                        try
                        {
                           tmp.client.Dispose();
                           tmp.stream.Dispose();
                           tmp.bw.Dispose();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
#if (VERBOSE)
                                    Console.WriteLine("Disposing error:" + ex.Message);
#endif
                        }
                        continue;
                     }
                     var pong = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[4] { data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3] }, 0);
                     if (pong != -3)
                     {
                        cons[i] = null;
                        try
                        {
                           tmp.client.Dispose();
                           tmp.stream.Dispose();
                           tmp.bw.Dispose();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
#if (VERBOSE)
                                    Console.WriteLine("Disposing error:" + ex.Message);
#endif
                        }
                        continue;
                     }

                     //socket is ok
                     conn = tmp;
                     break;
                  }

               }
            }
            else
            {
               if (i < last_index)
               {
                  continue;
               }
               if (Monitor.TryEnter(_locks[i]))
               {
                  try
                  {
                     if (cons[i] != null)
                     {
                        continue;
                     }
                     conn = new TcpConnection(hostname, port);
                     cons[i] = conn;
                     conn.Index = i;
                     break;
                  }
                  catch (Exception ex)
                  {
                     conn = null;
                     cons[i] = null;
#if (VERBOSE)
                                Console.WriteLine("Client socket creation error: " + ex.Message);
#endif
                     error_msg = ex.Message;
                     return BitConverter.GetBytes(-1);
                  }
                  finally
                  {
                     Monitor.Exit(_locks[i]);
                  }
               }
               else
               {
                  continue;
               }
            }
         }
         if (conn == null)
         {
            Thread.Sleep(150);
            continue;
         }
         else
         {
            break;
         }
      }

      bool error = false;
      try
      {
         var length = BitConverter.GetBytes(input.Length);
         var data = new byte[1024];
         conn.bw.Write(length); // Send the length first.
         conn.bw.Write(input);
         conn.bw.Flush();

         using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
         {
            int numBytesRead;
            int total;
            while (true)
            {
               numBytesRead = 0;
               while (numBytesRead < 4)
               {
                  int read = conn.stream.Read(data, numBytesRead, data.Length - numBytesRead);
                  numBytesRead += read;
                  if (read <= 0)
                  {
                     throw new LinqDbException("Read <= 0: " + read);
                  }
               }
               numBytesRead -= 4;
               total = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[4] { data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3] }, 0);
               if (total == -2)
               {
#if (VERBOSE)
                            Console.WriteLine("PINGER!!!");
#endif
                  continue;
               }
               break;
            }
            if (numBytesRead > 0)
            {
               var finput = new byte[numBytesRead];
               for (int i = 0; i < numBytesRead; i++)
               {
                  finput[i] = data[4 + i];
               }
               ms.Write(finput, 0, numBytesRead);
            }
            total -= numBytesRead;
            while (total > 0)
            {
               numBytesRead = conn.stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
               if (numBytesRead <= 0)
               {
                  throw new LinqDbException("numBytesRead <= 0: " + numBytesRead);
               }
               ms.Write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
               total -= numBytesRead;
            }
            conn.LastUsed = DateTime.Now;
            return ms.ToArray();
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
#if (VERBOSE)
                Console.WriteLine("Client socket error: " + ex.Message);
#endif
         error = true;
         error_msg = ex.Message;
         return BitConverter.GetBytes(-1);
      }
      finally
      {
         if (!error)
         {
            conn.ReleaseLock();
         }
         else
         {
            cons[conn.Index] = null;
            try
            {
               conn.client.Dispose();
               conn.stream.Dispose();
               conn.bw.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
#if (VERBOSE)
                        Console.WriteLine("Disposing error:" + ex.Message);
#endif
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The same issue is also in the server code:

```
var output = ServerLogic.Logic.Execute(input, db_path);
var length = BitConverter.GetBytes(output.Length); // You again need to get the length
pinger.Done = true;
lock (pinger._lock)
{
   bw.Write(length); // Send it before the data
   bw.Write(output);
   bw.Flush();
}
```

Full Server with the fix included:

```
class ServerSockets
{
   static Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

   static string db_path = null;
   static int port = 0;
   public static void Main()
   {
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);
      CommandHelper.ReadConfig(out db_path, out port);
      var sw = new Stopwatch();
      sw.Start();
      Console.WriteLine("Building in-memory indexes...");
      ServerLogic.Logic.ServerBuildIndexesOnStart(db_path);
      sw.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine("Done building in-memory indexes. It took: " + Math.Round(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 60000.0, 0) + " min.");

      Console.WriteLine("Listening on " + port);
      listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
      listener.Listen((int)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections);


      SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
      acceptEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(Service);
      bool willRaiseEvent = listener.AcceptAsync(acceptEventArg);
      if (!willRaiseEvent)
      {
         Service(null, acceptEventArg);
      }

      while (true)
      {
         try
         {
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
#if (VERBOSE)
                    Console.WriteLine("Still kicking...");
#endif
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("BAD ERROR... " + ex.Message);
         }
      }
   }
   static void OnProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      ServerLogic.Logic.Dispose();
   }
   private static void LoopToStartAccept()
   {
      SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
      acceptEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(Service);
      bool willRaiseEvent = listener.AcceptAsync(acceptEventArg);
      if (!willRaiseEvent)
      {
         Service(null, acceptEventArg);
      }
   }
   private static void HandleBadAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptEventArgs)
   {
#if (VERBOSE)
            Console.WriteLine("bad accept");
#endif
      acceptEventArgs.AcceptSocket.Dispose();
   }
   private static void Service(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
      {
         LoopToStartAccept();
         HandleBadAccept(e);
         return;
      }

      LoopToStartAccept();


      try
      {
         using (Socket soc = e.AcceptSocket)
         {
            var rg = new Random();
#if (VERBOSE)
                    Console.WriteLine("New socket: " + rg.Next(0, 1000000));
#endif
            //soc.NoDelay = true;
            soc.ReceiveTimeout = 60000;
            soc.SendTimeout = 60000;
            using (Stream stream = new NetworkStream(soc))
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(stream))
            {
               while (true) //reuse same connection for many commands
               {
                  byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                  {
                     int numBytesRead = 0;
                     while (numBytesRead < 4)
                     {
                        int read = 0;
                        try
                        {
                           read = stream.Read(data, numBytesRead, data.Length - numBytesRead);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                           //client closed connection
                           return;
                        }
                        numBytesRead += read;
                        if (read <= 0)
                        {
                           //throw new Exception("Read <= 0: " + read);
                           //client closed connection
                           return;
                        }
                     }
                     numBytesRead -= 4;
                     var total = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[4] { data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3] }, 0);
                     if (total == -3) //ping
                     {
                        //pong
                        bw.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(-3));
                        bw.Flush();
                        continue;
                     }
                     if (numBytesRead > 0)
                     {
                        var finput = new byte[numBytesRead];
                        for (int i = 0; i < numBytesRead; i++)
                        {
                           finput[i] = data[4 + i];
                        }
                        ms.Write(finput, 0, numBytesRead);
                     }
                     total -= numBytesRead;
                     while (total > 0)
                     {
                        numBytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        if (numBytesRead <= 0)
                        {
                           throw new Exception("numBytesRead <= 0: " + numBytesRead);
                        }
                        ms.Write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
                        total -= numBytesRead;
                     }
                     var input = ms.ToArray();
                     var pinger = new Pinger()
                     {
                        bw = bw
                     };
                     ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(f => { pinger.Do(); });
                     var output = ServerLogic.Logic.Execute(input, db_path);
                     var length = BitConverter.GetBytes(output.Length);
                     pinger.Done = true;
                     lock (pinger._lock)
                     {
                        bw.Write(length);
                        bw.Write(output);
                        bw.Flush();
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
#if (VERBOSE)
                Console.WriteLine("Socket error: " + ex.Message);
#endif
         //try
         //{
         //    var rg = new Random();
         //    File.WriteAllText("sock_error_" + rg.Next() + ".txt", ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace + (ex.InnerException != null ? (" " + ex.InnerException.Message + " " + ex.InnerException.StackTrace) : ""));
         //}
         //catch (Exception) { }
         return;
      }
      finally
      {
#if (VERBOSE)
                Console.WriteLine("Listener finally ");
#endif
      }
   }
}
```

For me with this two changes the code works in Windows and Linux. If you still have an issue you will need to provide also more details what data you are sending.

I did some more research on Linux after you posted your GitHub sample. As I already suggested in the comment below you should use the `Connect` method instead of the `ConnectAsync` to get better behavior. In my test on Raspbian and Arch Linux once you open lots of threads in the client you probably occupy all the ThreadPool so the Connect events stop happening and everything timeouts. Since your code loops on threads and waits you don't gain much by using the Async method anyway.

Here is the changed `TcpConnection` class to do synchronous connections:

```
public class TcpConnection
{
   object _lock = new object();
   bool _is_busy = false;
   public bool TakeLock()
   {
      lock (_lock)
      {
            if (_is_busy)
            {
               return false;
            }
            else
            {
               _is_busy = true;
               return true;
            }
      }
   }
   public void ReleaseLock()
   {
      _is_busy = false;
   }
   public bool Connected { get; set; }
   public string ConnError { get; set; }
   public Socket client { get; set; }
   public Stream stream { get; set; }
   public BinaryWriter bw { get; set; }
   public DateTime LastUsed { get; set; }
   public int Index { get; set; }
   public TcpConnection(string hostname, int port)
   {
      client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

      client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(hostname), port));
      if (client.Connected)
      {
#if (VERBOSE)
            Console.WriteLine("Connected immediately");
#endif
            //client.NoDelay = true;
            client.ReceiveTimeout = 60000;
            client.SendTimeout = 60000;
            this.stream = new NetworkStream(client);
            this.bw = new BinaryWriter(stream);
      }
      _is_busy = true;
      LastUsed = DateTime.Now;
   }
}
```

As a final comment I have to say your code is very complicated and does not follow best practices as already other people pointed out. I advise you to learn more about about multi threading and asynchronous programming and then improve the code which will also make it work better and more predictable.

Here are the links to the Microsoft samples on how to work with sockets asynchronously and the general documentation about how to do Async programming:

[Asynchronous Client Socket Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example)

[Asynchronous Server Socket Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example)

[Parallel Processing, Concurrency, and Async Programming in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-processing-and-concurrency)

Comment: If that was that easy... Nice catch though - the length is already added in parameter in clientsocket call as well as returned from server.execute - the code not shown. I've made a standalone project which demonstrates the problem: https://github.com/ren85/serverclientbug

Comment: After trying with your sample it shows there is an issue in Linux. From my debugging it looks like the issue is in the Client not the server. For me the ConnectAsync behaves strangely and in some cases never returns any connect event and the server shows it received a connection. I tried to replace it with the synchronous Connect and it works better but still timeouts on some connections. Will try to research more when i have time.

Comment: While the answer is very good given the sheer amount of design mistakes and code you had to deal with, Exception handling is still a pet peeve of mine. And this code catches Exception, wich is a cardinal Sin of Exception handling. It will catch Fatal Exceptions and those you should never catch. I got two articles on the thematic that I link in such cases:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: Yeah, the code is messy. I'll try this solution later, I wonder if it has anything to do with this bug https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/364

Comment: I have create a sample refactor of your code so it uses Tasks and async/await. If you are interested in improving the code in the future this might help you. Check my [fork of your code in GitHub](https://github.com/AlesDo/serverclientbug). I know it is late but was a fun exercise.

Comment: @AlesD I had a quick look at your code. It's a lot simpler, but it's not doing same things... For example, client creates TcpConnection every time it makes a call, that's expensive, previous version kept open sockets for reuse. Also what happens if server operation takes 3 minutes for example? The socket will timeout in your version, but previous version used special pinger class to maintain connection alive... Stil nice code, although not sure how much gain in all that async stuff...

Comment: Yes it does not do the same it opens a new connection every time. Just wanted to demonstrate how to make it nicer you can add the reusing of connections if you need it. I don't know your exact scenario to know if opening connections is expensive or not. If you say you might be waiting for a reply 3 minutes i don't think the opening and closing of the connections is what is slowing you down.

Comment: ok, thanks. Your earlier finding that sync client in my code works better really helped a great deal. (P.S. opening a  socket is expensive regardless)

Answer (score 5):

Let me start off with saying that the code is incredibly hard to understand. Not only does a lot of things happen within a method, you're also dealing with threads and (a lot of) locks. This makes things incredibly complex and very hard to pinpoint whats going on.

Its like trying to find a needle in the haystack. Except a hundred times worse because of timeouts, threads and locking mechanisms that constantly shift the needle.

I've ran this project on a `Windows 10` machine, with `Visual Studio 2019 Preview (16.4.0 preview 2.0)` and .NET Core runtime `3.1.0-preview1` (target framework being `3.0`).

Let me state one thing though, you have set the receive/set `timeout` for both the client and server to `60000`. I cannot reproduce your error using this. Because this timeout number is so big, everything eventually gets finished before a timeout can even occur.

In order to reproduce your errors I have downscaled the timeout considerably:

```cs
// File: ClientLib.cs
// Method: "ConnectedEvent(...)"
// Line 114-115
e.ConnectSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;

// Lowering it even more multiplies the errors.
```

The above now gives me about ~5 errors, which then again simply happens because of this code (where the `Pinger` is instantiated):

```cs
// File: Server\Program.cs
// Method: "Service(...)"
Thread.Sleep(random.Next(100, 1000));
```

where also the following happens just above:

```cs
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(f => { pinger.Do(); });
```

The server uses the `ThreadPool` and it can handle *8 operations*<sup>1</sup> concurrently on it. Not only are you using the `ThreadPool` when a `Socket` connection is established, but also when you do a `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(...)`.

This means big trouble when the client starts trying to establish a huge amount of connections. As this can cause timeouts too.

One way of increasing the threads in the `ThreadPool`:

```cs
public static void Main()
{   
    int w, c = 0;
    ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out w, out c);
    Console.WriteLine($"ThreadPool max: {w} worker threads {c} completion threads");

    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);

    ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out w, out c);
    Console.WriteLine($"ThreadPool max: {w} worker threads {c} completion threads");

    /// other code...
}
```

But really, just removing these two lines solves the problem:

```cs
var random = new Random();
Thread.Sleep(random.Next(100, 1000));
```

<sup>1</sup> This can differ per machine, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=netcore-3.0#remarks). You can check it on your machine by using [ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.getminthreads?view=netcore-3.0).

Comment: On windows 10 it **is** working as is, the problem only occurs on linux machine. `var random = new Random();
Thread.Sleep(random.Next(100, 1000));` is simulating work that is done in server.execute and takes similar time (or it could take 10x longer). I've tried setting min worker threads on linux - same problem.

Comment: @ren Aha, ok got it. You need both the client and server running on a linux machine?

Comment: yes. I also tried server on windows, client on linux and it failed similarly. So the client needs to be on linux at least.

Comment: @ren Ok, sorry I misunderstood that part (and also the `Thread.Sleep()` part). I'll try that setup tomorrow. Does it matter on what kind of distro?

Comment: I run on ubuntu 19.10 but I quess it don't matter

Comment: @ren Thank you for the information. Look I've ran the scenarios on a linux machine using docker containers and they work perfectly fine. It works even faster and with a lower failure rate (~5 at maximum) than on Windows... So I really cannot reproduce your situation, making me conclude that your linux machine is not properly configured. I cannot think of another reason after having spent a lot of hours to test everything. There is simply nothing wrong with `Sockets` on .NET Core.